# How to get Point of Object attached to a other Object relative to its Rotation?

Tags: c#, rotation, monogame

I need Help at this Problem. I want to get the Position of the yellow Bullet relative to the rotation of the guy. Can someone help me ?
I have the position of the guy and the rotation Angle(-3,2 to 3,2)

Thank you in advance
[Guy without Rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nfpU.png)
[Guy with Rotation(-1,5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V96jw.png)

**I already Tried:**

WorldOrigin:Player Location

```
new Bullet(direction, new Vector2(worldOrigin.X - 10, worldOrigin.Y + 30),rotation)
```

To set the bullet at the gun end but when i rotate my player the bullet ist still down right and not for example up left when i look to the left.

I tried to set the origin where i draw to the gun of the player texture but that didnt worked aswell :(

**Solution:**
Now i just draw the bullet at the Gun. I used the rotation of the Player and added 30 to it. And i draw then the bullet at a radius of 50 and a angle PlayerRotation + 30.

```
public Bullet(Vector2 target, Vector2 pos, float rotation)
    {
        this.target = target;
        this.pos = pos;
        this.rotation = rotation;

        Vector2 newPos = new Vector2();
        newPos.X = pos.X + (float)(50 * Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(RadianToDegree(rotation) + 30)));
        newPos.Y = pos.Y + (float)(50 * Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(RadianToDegree(rotation) + 30)));

        this.pos = newPos;
    }
```

Comment: post what u have tried

Comment: @Raizzen I did it

Comment: This question is very ambiguous. Please take the time to elaborate more on what your problem is. Also, include examples of how you are drawing and updating your sprites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i just draw the bullet at the Gun. I used the rotation of the Player and added 30 to it. And i draw then the bullet at a radius of 50 and a angle PlayerRotation + 30.

```
public Bullet(Vector2 target, Vector2 pos, float rotation)
{
    this.target = target;
    this.pos = pos;
    this.rotation = rotation;

    Vector2 newPos = new Vector2();
    newPos.X = pos.X + (float)(50 * Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(RadianToDegree(rotation) + 30)));
    newPos.Y = pos.Y + (float)(50 * Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(RadianToDegree(rotation) + 30)));

    this.pos = newPos;
}
```